# Convert string to URL in column

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I just want to convert IDs as strings to URLs automatically. I tried this:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://myjira.com/projects/BUWDI/issues/";A2);A2)
```

I got an error...

What do you think?

Comment: Welcome. What is the error that you got? Also, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: what does the error say?

Answer (score -1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), 
 HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://myjira.com/projects/BUWDI/issues/"; A2:A); A2:A); ))
```

[image: 0]